# <exec command> vs gtk-launch <exec command>

Tags: bash, command-line, gnome, gtk

These days I noticed that there is one game called Four-in-a-row which opens through GNOME GUI when it is clicked but it doesn't open when I type in terminal the command `gtk-launch org.gnome.Four-in-a-row.desktop` inside the `/usr/share/applications/` path although there are some applications which don't open also and other ones that open, now I wondering to know what is the difference in type in terminal or in a bash script:

- `gtk-launch org.gnome.Four-in-a-row.desktop #inside /usr/share/applications/`
- `four-in-a-row  #directly it works and the application is opened`

and from these two options which command is executed when the app icon is clicked and opened at Show Applications list in the GNOME GUI?